# How to find robust counterpart of sum of logit functions?

Tags: nonlinear-programming, duality, dual, robust-optimization

Suppose function $\mu_i(y):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a logit function, $\mu_i(y)=1/(1+\exp(-y))$. Also, we assume that $\mathbf{x}_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d$. I am wondering how it is possible to find the robust counterpart of the following problem?
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^d} &\left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \mu_i(\mathbf{x}^T \theta)\: \:\: s.t. \:\:\:\|\theta-\hat{\theta}\|_H \le \gamma  \right\} \ge b
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $H$ is a positive definite matrix and $a_i, \gamma, b$ are positive numbers. If it is not possible to find an exact robust counterpart, I would be thankful for any idea about how to find a conservative approximation.

I crossposted to Math.SE as well:  [Dual of sum of two sigmoid functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554732/dual-of-sum-of-two-sigmoid-functions).

Comment: You're looking for the convex conjugate (Fenchel Dual) of this problem? Your logit function is close to some found in the table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate